# Populate Jenkins changes with diff between current tag and last tag

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline that is building releases that are tagged.  The issue is that nothing currently registers any changes for the build, since each tag is a single build/deploy.

How do I:

1. Make changes to the Jenkins changes feature form within the Pipeline
2. Figure out the branch name for the previous release and run a git diff to get the list of commits.
3. Take those git diff commit messages and set them to the Changes in Jenkins.

Ideally for #2 I would want to skip pre-release tags, ex. If I am releasing `1.1.0-rc1` it should dhow a diff between it and `1.0.9` (the latest release before `1.1.0*`)

Is the "changes" feature I mention above also called "changeset"?